# Missing a Generic/Text Only printer driver?

Tags: windows, drivers, printer, printing

I have a program that needs a printer with the Generic/Text Only driver to print shipping documents.
Some users in China (who use Windows XP and Windows 7) don't have the option to select this driver when installing a printer. The Generic/Text Only option is missing from the list of Manufacturers and Printers.
How can they "install" this driver? Can it be downloaded somewhere? I tried googling around, but couldn't find a reliable source. Most of the time the link leads you to install some sort of driver updater.

Answer (score 0):

Would they happen to be running the Chinese version of Windows?  It's a generic driver that ships with Windows from Microsoft.  You should be able to get off the appropriate Windows CD/DVD or disk image.  You might have to use the English language version of Windows to find it.  I wonder if it got left off the Chinese version or if they're running legit Windows.  It's so easy in Kowloon to get pirated copies that many people don't realize that's what they are.

Comment: Yes. They're using the Chinese version of Windows XP and Windows 7. I know that this driver ships free with Windows. I've seen it in Windows 98 and up. It is weird to me that all computers in the Chinese office are missing this driver. One of the guys there looked at his personal laptop computer (also using a Chinese version of Windows) and it does have the driver installed.